# Using default and user selected filters for a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, query-string, connection-filters

I want to filter a main/task list based on what's being selected in a Sharepoint List Filter Web part. However if there is a "querystring" in the URL, then I want the List filter autoselected to whats being provided in the "querystring".

This is should in turn filter the main list. If the user selects a different item in the SP List Filter then this should filter the main list and override whats being provided in the "querystring".

Is this possible? From what I know SP List Filter does not accept filter values from QueryString Filter web part.

Comment: You might need to use javascript to check the query string, then update the list filter.

Comment: will this also update the master/task list?